# Spring Service method with multiple transactions

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-transactions

Hi I have spring service method(A Method) which will do two operations.first it will save the data into database through hibernate dao method(B Method).then it will give signal to the spring-activiti workflow(C Method) to move to next stage.Now I am using spring transaction manager.and I am using transactions as below.so here my question is if some exception is caught in workflow method then database changes should not be reverted back..

```
 @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
@Override
public WorkflowResponseBO saveDraft(PETIncidentBO pETIncident) throws DDMApplicationException {
Investigation investigation = savePETIncident(pETIncident);
WorkflowResponseBO workflowResponse = null;
if (pETIncident.getWorkflowId() == null) {
    workflowResponse = initiateWorkflow(pETIncident, investigation);
}
return workflowResponse;
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, readOnly = false, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
private Investigation savePETIncident(PETIncidentBO pETIncident) throws DDMApplicationException {
LOGGER.info("Entered Method :: savePETIncident");
Investigation investigation = null;
try {
    if (pETIncident.getWorkflowId() != null) {
    investigation = investigationDao.findInvestigationByWorkflowId(pETIncident.getWorkflowId());
    }

    // Incident Data
    Incident incident = getIncidentDetails(investigation, pETIncident);

    // Investigation Data
    if (investigation == null) {
    investigation = new Investigation();
    investigation.setInvestigatedInvolvedPerson(getIncidentInvolvedPersonDetails(incident, pETIncident));
    MasterLookup allegedViolationType = null;
    allegedViolationType = masterLookupDao.findMasterLookupByShortDesc(DDMConstants.PROBATIONARY_TERMINATION_LOOKUP);
    investigation.setAllegedViolationType(allegedViolationType);
    CollectiveBargainingAgreement collectiveBargainingAgreement = null;
    collectiveBargainingAgreement = collectiveBargainingAgreementDao.findCollectiveBargainingAgreementbyId(pETIncident.getCba().getCollectiveBargainingAgreementId());
    investigation.setCollectiveBargainingAgreement(collectiveBargainingAgreement);
    investigation.setIncident(incident);
    }
    // updating the address and rehire status of the involved person
    investigation = updateInvesigationInvolvedPersonDetails(investigation, pETIncident);

    InvestigationUnstructuredContent content = getInvestigationUnstructuredContentDetails(investigation, pETIncident);

    content = getInvestigationUnstContentDeliveryDetails(pETIncident, content, investigation.getInvestigatedInvolvedPerson().getPerson());

    investigation.getInvestigationUnstConts().add(content);

    investigation = getInvestigationAssignedPersonDetails(investigation, incident, pETIncident);

    if (investigation.getInvestigationId() == null) {
    investigationDao.createinvestigation(investigation);
    } else {
    investigationDao.updateinvestigation(investigation);
    }

} catch (DDMDBException de) {
    LOGGER.error(de);
    DDMServicesExceptionHandler.handleException(de);
} catch (DDMApplicationException da) {
    LOGGER.error(da);
    DDMServicesExceptionHandler.handleException(da);
} catch (Exception e) {
    LOGGER.error(e);
    DDMServicesExceptionHandler.handleException(e);
}
LOGGER.info("Exited Method :: savePETIncident");
return investigation;
}
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, readOnly = false, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
private WorkflowResponseBO initiateWorkflow(PETIncidentBO pETIncident, Investigation investigation) throws DDMApplicationException {
// updating the workflow id in the investigation table
WorkflowResponseBO workflowResponse = null;
PETWorkflowDetailsBO petWorkflowDetails = new PETWorkflowDetailsBO();
petWorkflowDetails.setCbaId(investigation.getCollectiveBargainingAgreement().getCollectiveBargainingAgreementId().toString());
petWorkflowDetails.setInitiatorEmployeeId(pETIncident.getIncidentCreatorEmployeeId());
petWorkflowDetails.setInvovledPersonEmployeeId(pETIncident.getInvolvedPersonDeliveryDetails().getPerson().getEmployeeId());
petWorkflowDetails.setReasonForTermination(pETIncident.getReasonForTermination().getLookupShortDesc());
petWorkflowDetails.setTerminationDate(DdmDateUtils.dateToString(pETIncident.getTerminationDate(), DDMConstants.DISPLAY_DATE_FORMAT));
workflowResponse = petWorkflowService.reportProbationaryEmployeeTermination(petWorkflowDetails);
investigation.setWorkflowId(workflowResponse.getProcessId());
try {
    investigationDao.updateinvestigation(investigation);
} catch (DDMDBException e) {
    LOGGER.error("Error while updating investigation table");
    DDMServicesExceptionHandler.handleException(e);

}
if (workflowResponse == null) {
    workflowResponse = new WorkflowResponseBO();
    workflowResponse.setProcessId(pETIncident.getWorkflowId());
    workflowResponse.setTaskId(pETIncident.getTaskId());
}
return workflowResponse;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When class based proxies spring loaded the class it and wrapped the saveDraft method inside a transaction.  Since spring is now out of the loop in handling any further call to methods in this class it will not create nested transactions.

Consider the use of AspectJ mode if you expect self-invocations to be wrapped with transactions as well. In this case, there will not be a proxy in the first place; instead, the target class will be weaved (that is, its byte code will be modified) in order to turn @Transactional into runtime behavior on any kind of method.

Or you could use programmatic transactions.